# D3: Click on map and trace the closest path until the coast

Tags: javascript, d3.js

For the application I would like to build, the user can click on any point of the map, and the nearest river path could be identified and animated until it reaches the coast.  I used D3 to draw a bunch of paths (rivers) from a geojson file, each path is a feature with the geometry type LineString. I figured I could use d3's voronoi to identify the closest path when user clicks on a point. My biggest problem is, I could probably identify to closest river segment, but I am not sure how to automatically trace the rest of the paths until it reaches the coast. For example, you can see in the image I attached, one path is highlighted, but I would also like the paths after it to be highlighted. My only idea is that I could create a new geojson file that with all possible stream paths (as a whole, not individual segments), how would I create this file from a file where each individual segment is a path? I provided 3 features from the my geojson file at the end just to give you an idea of how my current data is organized

[image]

```
{"type": "FeatureCollection","crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },"features": [{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "arcid": 15, "grid_code": 1, "from_node": 4074, "to_node": 4069, "Shape_Leng": 24.8000011779 }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ 128.257362464927638, 26.8747231358752 ], [ 128.257361002021611, 26.874947030137374 ] ] } },{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "arcid": 16, "grid_code": 1, "from_node": 4075, "to_node": 4070, "Shape_Leng": 24.8000011779 }, "geometry":{ "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ 128.258485955739388, 26.874729034949482 ], [ 128.258484495046019, 26.87495292926857 ] ] } },{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "arcid": 23, "grid_code": 1, "from_node": 4083, "to_node": 4068, "Shape_Leng": 69.318110594900006 }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ 128.256990163500433, 26.874385326154584 ], [ 128.256674423121041, 26.874943420716903 ] ] } }]}
```

Comment: I think I edited the my question so that there is only one question being asked (how would I create this file from a file where each individual segment is a path?), is it still too broad?